# Laravel Eloquent Events Implementation

Tags: laravel, events, eloquent, laravel-events

I am updating my model instance or inserting a new one like this:

```
$model = Model::updateOrCreate([id' => $request['id']],
$model_to_update_array);
```

I want to execute some code only when existing **model instance ('tourist') was updated** (and NOT when a new one was created or nothing changes).

I've read https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events about Eloquent events and it seems to me that I need to use *updated* or *updating* event. As I understand these events are 'built-in' in Laravel, so I don't have to use a lot of stuff from here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/events

I haven't found a tutorial showing how to implement Eloquent events. Since I am new to events conception at all,  it's hard for me to understand how to use them. Can anyone drop a link to a good tutorial about Eloquent events (not events in general, but Eloqeunt events in particular) or maybe it can be shortly explained here?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add Eloquent event for a particular model is to overwrite its `boot()` method:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::updating(function ($model) {

    });
}
```

When you put this in your model the anonymous function will run every time when the model is being updated. Please note that there is a difference between calling `static::updating()` and `static::updated()` depending on when you want to execute your code.

Comment: Thank you, TheFallen. Where can I read about the difference (updated, updating)?

Comment: @SergejFomin, the documentation doesn't say much about it, but basically `*ing` events are being called before the actual event and `*ed` are called after the event. So in your case if you put your code in `static::updating()` it will run before the actual database update and in `static::updated()` it will run after that.

Comment: Hi! So I included protected static function boot().... in my model. How do I use it to check if the model was updated in the Controller?

Comment: @SergejFomin, please post another question with the relevant controller code.

Comment: i've posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698659/laravel-eloquent-events-implement-to-save-model-if-updated

Answer (score 0):

@TheFallen gave a great answer to this problem in another thread on StackOverflow, please read if you are interested in thoroughly explained solution:

[Laravel Eloquent Events - implement to save model if Updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698659/laravel-eloquent-events-implement-to-save-model-if-updated)