# Laravel Eloquent Events - implement to save model if Updated

Tags: laravel-events

I have such code in the controller:

```
for($i=0; $i<$number_of_tourists; $i++) {

$tourist = Tourist::updateOrCreate(['doc_number' => $request['doc_number'][$i]],
$tourist_to_update);

}
```

so, the updateOrCreate method can 1) Update record, 2) Create a new one 3) Leave record untouched if $tourist_to_update equals to what's already in the DB.

**I want to save $tourist_to_update into $array[] only when a record in 'tourist" table is being updated** (not when a new record created or nothing changes).

As I know, there are Eloquent events https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events  which have *updating* and *updated* events, which seem to match my needs.

The problem is I watched&read several tutorials and still don't understand how to use them.

I know how-to-register a Eloquent event  in Tourist model:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::updating(function ($model) {

    });
}
```

Could anyone explain how can I achive my goal with Eloquent events?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you want to create a new array `$array` which contains only the records which were updated?

Comment: @ TheFallen  yes:)  exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit more complex approach, but if you want to get only updated records which have their data changed this is working. In your controller method add:

```
app()->singleton('touristsCollector', function ($app) {
    $collector = new \stdClass;
    $collector->updated = [];

    return $collector;
});

for($i = 0; $i < $number_of_tourists; $i++) {
    $tourist = Tourist::updateOrCreate(
        ['doc_number' => $request['doc_number'][$i]],
        $tourist_to_update
    );
}

$collector = resolve('touristsCollector');
var_dump( $collector->updated ); // Only updated tourists which have data changed
```

This will basically add to the app container a standard PHP class which will collect all the updated tourists from the model event. In your model add this:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::updated(function ($model) {
        $collector = resolve('touristsCollector');
        $collector->updated[] = $model;
    });
}
```

This will basically get the PHP class from the app container add the tourist model only if some properties of it have been updated.

Comment: wow, that's what I was looking for - using Eloquent Models to get this thing done!:) You are really The MASTER!:) I have some questions though: I see no difference if i change 'static:updated' to 'static:updating'. So what's the difference?:)

Comment: where can I read more about 'app()->singleton' and '\stdClass'?:)

Comment: @SergejFomin, `updating` event will fire even though properties are the same, `updated` will fire only if there are some changes of the data, so you need the `updated` event.

Comment: @SergejFomin, this is the app container binding https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#binding and `stdClass` is an anonymous PHP library standard class, you could use a plain array instead of this class.

Answer (score 0):

If the model has been created the property `wasRecentlyCreated` will be set to true, so this is how you can check if the model is new or updated:

```
$updated = [];

for($i = 0; $i < $number_of_tourists; $i++) {
    $currentTourist = ['doc_number' => $request['doc_number'][$i]];
    $tourist = Tourist::updateOrCreate($currentTourist, $tourist_to_update);

    if ( $tourist->wasRecentlyCreated ) {
        continue; // Go to next loop if this tourist was created now
    }

    $updated[] = $tourist;
}
```

Comment: thank you, TheFallen. But I think there is a problem. 'updateOrCreate', besides updating and creating, has a third behaviour: 
3) Leave record untouched if $tourist_to_update equals to what's already in the DB. I think that you code will add a tourist which is already in db and doesn't need to be updated or created, to the $updated[ ] array. I've just implemented your code. yes, it does add unchanged tourists to array $updated...:(

Comment: @SergejFomin, ye, you are correct, to get only the updated ones you might compare the `updated_at` timestamp to the current time or check my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to execute a specific code when a row in tourist table was updated, I would recommend to create an [observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#observers) to listen for `updated` or `create` calls.

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Tourist;

class TouristObserver
{
    /**
     * Listen to the User created event.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Tourist $user)
    {
        // this will always trigger when you created a new entry
    }

    /**
     * Listen to the User deleting event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Tourist $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated(Tourist $user)
    {
        // this will always trigger when actually a row was updated
    }
}
```

All you have to do is to register the observer in `AppServiceProvider` like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    Tourist::observe(\App\Observer\TouristObserver::class);
}
```